Running function with ProcessPoolExecutor on a SLURM cluster with submitit
I'm trying to run a function with submitit on a SLURM cluster.
The function uses ProcessPoolExecutor:
def func():
    print("Hello world!")

def parallel_executor():
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=24) as executor_inner:
        j = executor_inner.submit(func)
        j.result()

I'm then submitting the function parallel_executor with submitit to the SLURM cluster:
executor = submitit.AutoExecutor()
j = executor.submit(parallel_executor)

But I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/X/venvs/smac_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/submitit/core/submission.py", line 55, in process_job
    result = delayed.result()
  File "/home/X/venvs/smac_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/submitit/core/utils.py", line 133, in result
    self._result = self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/X/meta_hpo/test_submitit.py", line 33, in parallel_executor
    j.result()
  File "X/Python/3.10.8-GCCcore-12.2.0/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 458, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "X/Python/3.10.8-GCCcore-12.2.0/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 403, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "X/Python/3.10.8-GCCcore-12.2.0/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 244, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "X/Python/3.10.8-GCCcore-12.2.0/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function func at 0x151b9dbed6c0>: attribute lookup func on __main__ failed

Is there a fix for this issue or another way to run a function that has multiple "sub-tasks"?

The problem is that you are using __main__, are you running this in an interactive session? Things in interactive sessions can't be "pickled". Try putting this code in a file, and running the file.

Another solution is to switch out pickle for dill, which is a much more capable "pickling" library.

In essence, everything you want to run on another process needs to be sent to that other process. The only data you can send over a socket from one process to the other are strings. So all your objects need to be converted to strings and then reconstructed on the other side. pickle is OK, but not very good at it. That's why you are getting PicklingErrors

@RobinDeSchepper thanks for the response! I'm using a file (the submission part is under if name=='main').

Ah, can you see if you can override which pickler these tools use? You could also use mpi4py. I'm assuming this is on a supercomputer cluster? They usually communicate over MPI. I also have a library called mpipool. Both are excellent choices for SLURM/MPI parallel processing

submitit has a page dedicated to these issues: https://github.com/facebookincubator/submitit/blob/1.5.1/docs/tips.md
